# Image of Button not visible in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i´ve got a problem with a Button that i want to place within the ColumnHeader of my DataGrid. I want to place an Image in that Button but that image isn´t visible. Any guess how to fix this?

Here´s the xaml code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="bemiNr" Visibility="Visible" FontSize="18" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=bemiNr}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <Grid Margin="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Bemi Nr" />
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnFilterView" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="30" Width="30" Source="/TestDB;component/Assets/filter-outline_black.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

[image: filterimage not visible]

Comment: Yes, the path is correct. I have some other buttons displaying images (not in the Header though) and they are all visible

Comment: Build Action is set to Resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated in the comments that you've set the build action to "Resource", try replacing `/TestDB;component/Assets/filter-outline_black.png` with `pack://application:,,,/TestDB;component/Assets/filter-outline_black.png`.